# Getting Coordinates of Polygon Using Matlab

Tags: matlab, geometry, polygon, voronoi

I have the following plot generated using Matlab. The Red lines are generated using the Voronoi function and the black rectangular box using rectangle function.

(1) I want to get the coordinates of the polygons inside the rectangles (coordinates in clockwise or ccw direction) 
Matlab code given below:

```
a=12.5e-3;
b=30e-3;
vcellsx=[0.0105089656997958,0.00245744063039010,0.00770055845183299,0.00439574383828746,0.00946500286388402];
vcellsy=[0.00762846536914593,0.00753251573928093,0.0141986654670819,0.0249248588368887,0.0226118728283549];

[vx,vy]=voronoi(vcellsx,vcellsy);
plot(vx,vy,'r-','LineWidth', 2);

hold on
rectangle('Position',[0 0 a b])
```

[edit] 
I am looking for coordinates of the domains as shown in the figure.
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzxYGJhdC2A4Vl9jUTVDU204NEk/view

Comment: What you exactly mean by removing lines outside the rectangle? Some part of the lines or the whole open lines?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use,

```
[V,C] = voronoin(X)
```

function which returns Voronoi vertices `V` and the Voronoi cells `C` of the Voronoi diagram of `X`.

After you get `C` you have to check for cells not including `1` because those including `1` represent open regions.

Finally, the corners can be found in `v(c{i},1),v(c{i},2)`.

You can add the following code to the end of your code.

```
x = [vcellsx' vcellsy'];
[v,c] = voronoin(x);
for i = 1:length(c)
    if all(c{i}~=1)
        patch(v(c{i},1),v(c{i},2),i); % use color i.
    end
end
```

And here is the result:

[image]

Comment: I am looking for coordinates of the domains as shown in the figure.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzxYGJhdC2A4Vl9jUTVDU204NEk/view?usp=sharing